# MQTT-SN on Raspberry pi3 , 6lowpan over BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ipv6, mqtt

I'm trying to set a MQTT-SN  broker (rsmb) ,and using several pi3 as clients.

First , I will build a 6lowpan over ble connection.

Setting pi3 (RASPBIAN JESSIE kernel v4.4)

```
sudo su
hciconfig hci0 reset
modprobe bluetooth_6lowpan
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/6lowpan_enable
hciconfig hci0 leadv
```

BLE gateway (Ubuntu 14.04)

```
sudo su
hciconfig hci0 reset
modprobe bluetooth_6lowpan
echo 35 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/6lowpan_psm
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
echo "connect *my_pi3_bluetooth_address* 1" > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/6lowpan_control
ifconfig bt0 add 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64
service radvd restart
```

And my 6lowpan over ble connection is working .

Now I want to use MQTT-SN protocol within this connection.

If I only uses local connection,it's fine.

But If I uses 6lowpan over BLE connection,i think that some of packets are lost.

```
ERROR Keep alive error: timed out while waiting for a PUBLISH gateway
```

The detail is in this url. [Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQb0k.jpg)

How can I slove this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I need to unplug the network Cable, and it's all fine.