# IPSP functionalities (6LoWPAN over BTLE) can be obtained using a BTLE 4.0 (not 4.2) adapter?

Tags: bluetooth, btle

I'm developing an application for Linux that uses 6LoWPAN over BTLE (Bluetooth Low Energy). I have read that 6LoWPAN over BTLE requires the support of 
Data Packet Length Extension, that is a feature introduced by the BTLE 4.2 standard and, therefore, should not be available using the common BTLE 4.0 adapters.

This is an issue for me, because I've looked for an USB dongle for PC supporting BTLE 4.2, compatible with BlueZ stack for Linux, but nothing seems to be available at the moment, as it can be read here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/btstack-dev/IeA92qNGR9c

However, I have read at the link

[MQTT-SN on Raspberry pi3 , 6lowpan over BLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107956/mqtt-sn-on-raspberry-pi3-6lowpan-over-ble)

that it is possible to support 6LoWPAN over BTLE using some Raspberry PI 3.

The BTLE chipset integrated in Raspberry PI 3 is the Broadcom BCM43438 
that is declared (only) BTLE 4.1 compatible.

Is it possible to create a working 6LoWPAN connection between 2 RaspPI3
boards, using only BTLE 4.0/4.1-compatible adapters ?
How the adapters manage the compatibility with 6LoWPAN using short BTLE frames since the Data Length Extension is not available ?

Can the previous limitation be overcome by a firmware update for Broadcom chipsets that is integrated in the last Linux kernel, thus adding support for Data Packet Length Extension via software ?

Do you know some USB dongle that supports (or that can be updated to support) BTLE 4.2 + Data Length Extension and that is compatible with BlueZ Linux stack ?

Comment: Where did you read that 6LoWPAN over BTLE requires the support of Data Packet Length Extension?

Comment: The maximum frame size for BTLE without Packet Length Extensions is 22 bytes (18 bytes for payload), that should be not compatible with 6LoWPAN addressing...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you got 22/18 bytes from. For each packet, L2CAP data of 27 bytes can be transmitted. L2CAP has a 4 byte header.

L2CAP has built-in fragmentation/reassembly support so an L2CAP packet of more than 27 bytes can be sent even if the Link Layer MTU is 27 bytes, so there should be no problem running 6LoWPAN on a controller that does not support LE Data Packet Length Extension.

Comment: The limitation of 23 bytes can be found here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3478807/ (paragraph 2.4). Are you sure that 6LoWPAN for BTLE exploits L2CAP fragmentation/reassembly ?

Comment: There is something called source critism. That article has many errors. Have you for example heard of a BLE controller that can have 5917 simultaneous connections, as mentioned in the article? Anyway, L2CAP segmentation / reassembly is definitely supported even in 4.0.